# How do I reduce/change delay after crawling?

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

Has anybody experience with using Crawler4j?

I followed the example from [the project page](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/basic/) to realize my own crawler. The crawler is working fine and crawls very fast. The only thing is that I always have a delay of 20–30 seconds. Is there a way to avoid the waiting time?

Comment: You mean processing or waiting time? The only waiting related setting that I known about is "[politeness delay](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/wiki/Configurations#Politeness)".

Answer (score 2):

Just checked crawler4j [source code](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/). The [CrawerController.start](https://code.google.com/p/crawler4j/source/browse/src/main/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/crawler/CrawlController.java?r=9bc8c1b54eedfd8fd0384822517159d997670e5e#141) method have a lot of fixed 10 seconds "pauses" going on to make sure that threads are done and ready to be cleaned up.

```
// Make sure again that none of the threads
// are
// alive.
logger.info("It looks like no thread is working, waiting for 10 seconds to make sure...");
sleep(10);

// ... more code ...

logger.info("No thread is working and no more URLs are in queue waiting for another 10 seconds to make sure...");
sleep(10);

// ... more code ...

logger.info("Waiting for 10 seconds before final clean up...");
sleep(10);
```

Also, the main loop checks every 10 seconds to know if the crawling threads are done:

```
while (true) {
    sleep(10);
    // code to check if some thread is still working
}

protected void sleep(int seconds) {
   try {
       Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
   } catch (Exception ignored) {
   }
}
```

So it may be worth to fine tune those calls and reduce the sleeping time.

A better solution, if you can spare some time, would be to rewrite this method. I would replace the `List<Thread> threads` by an [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), its [awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method would be particularly handy. Unlike Sleep, `awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` will return immediately if all tasks are done.